# Selenium “Unable to find a matching set of capabilities” despite driver being in /usr/local/bin

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I was trying to open the firefox browser using selenium webdriver. I already have my geckodriver in `/usr/local/bin` as I'm working on project of web scraping and crawling.

- Geckodriver version-21.0
- Firefox version-64.0 (quantum)
- Selenium version- 3.141.0.

Also tried geckodriver of versions i.e 17.0,19.0,23.0; to find the combination.

What I have tried is in the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://kissanime.ru/")
driver.maximize_window()
```

While executing the code it popped an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "downloader.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct 32/64 bit version of the binaries - it should be uniform - e.g. if the firefox is 64bit, so must be the geckodriver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

Your main issue may be the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.23.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Ensure GeckoDriver is present in the specified location.
- Ensure GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v64.0.*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Pass the argument **executable_path** along with the absolute path of the *GeckoDriver* while initiating the WebDriver/WebBrowser session as follows:

  - *Windows OS* format:

    ```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
    ```
  - *Linux* and *MAC OS X* format:

    ```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
    ```
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: I'm alredy using the latest version of selenium i.e 3.141.0 for python, have latest firefox version i.e 64.0 and latest geckodriver i.e 23.0, as you recommened to clear cached memory tried that too and also passed executable_path but ended with the same error.

Comment: @DevanshMishra Can you update the question with your current code trials and error trace logs?