# Geckodriver, unable to find a set of matching capabilities

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, geckodriver

So for now I have just a small script with an issue that is running on my Ubuntu Windows Subsystem, but I can't make the script to run since I get a weird error beucase of geckodriver.

I have also tried the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953524/selenium-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-despite-driver-being-in), but it didn't work.
Everything is running inside my virtual environment, python 3.6, latest version of selenium and geckodriver(from their website). <strike>This will be running on a server where Firefox won't be installed so that's why I'm using geckodriver and the instalation of Firefox is out of question.</strike>

```py
from selenium import webdriver
geckodriver = '/home/user/test_env/geckodriver'

def test():
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('-headless')
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver, 
                                 firefox_options=options)

    browser.get('https://www.duckduckgo.com')
    browser.save_screenshot('test.png')

    browser.quit()

def main():
    # Try running the script
    test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Error from the line

```
 webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver, firefox_options=options)
```

Edit:
I have installed Firefox on my machine and moved it to /usr/local/bin and gave it +x permissions and I've also moved geckodriver to /usr/local/bin  but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Your script won't work without Firefox, Geckodriver is a 'link' between your Selenium tests and the browser. For more detail read [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-should-I-use-the-Gecko-Driver-in-Selenium-3-0)

Comment: Yep. I was aware of that and I've installed Firefox into /usr/local/bin and gave it +x permission but I still have that error