# Why can't run geckodriver in selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Download chromedriver and extract it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/debian/Downloads/chromedriver')
```

It works fine.
Now to test geckodriver for firefox,my firefox version is 78.0.2 (64-bit),the latest version,i have downloaded the `geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz` and extract it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/debian/Downloads/geckodriver')
```

It encounter some issues:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953524/selenium-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-despite-driver-being-in/53953692#53953692), [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601126/unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-with-selenium-3-4-3-firefox-54-0/44601664#44601664) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002958/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a/52006033#52006033) discussion and update me if any of them helps you?

Answer (score -1):

first check if selenium are downloaded with no error and make sure that the webdriver are downloaded in the path in this code `driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/debian/Downloads/geckodriver')`

that's should fix your problem