# WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Possible firefox version mismatch. You must use GeckoDriver instead for Firefox 48+with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, marionette, geckodriver

I tried to [follow an example](https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/) how to parse websites via python and selenium.
But I am running always into the following problem: calling the function *webdriver.Firefox*
opens a firefox instance, but no website via get could be called, it seems: the whole code is blocking in function Firefox (see: print("open call never reached")) The browser is opening and after ca. 30 seconds an exception causes the broswer to exit, with message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Possible firefox version mismatch. You must use GeckoDriver instead for Firefox 48+. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpl5dm_azd If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details
```

So what do I am wrong here ? How could I set the profile right ?
I tried to set marionette mode True, but got the error : "Unable to find a matching set of capabilities"

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False

options = Options()
options.log.level = "trace"
options.headless = True

binary = FirefoxBinary("/usr/bin/firefox")
pathDriver = "./geckodriver" 
testUrl="https://duckduckgo.com/"

print("will create firefox instance")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,options=options,capabilities=cap,executable_path=pathDriver)
print("open call never reached")
browser.get(testUrl)

webdriver.quit()
```

My test environment:

```
$ name -a
Linux 5.5.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.5.17-1~bpo10+1 (2020-04-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Also I downloaded the latest selenium and the geckodriver
here see what versions I do use:

```
$ python3 –version
Python 3.7.3
```

```
$ pip3 freeze | grep sel
selenium==3.141.0
```

```
$ geckodriver -V
geckodriver 0.27.0 (7b8c4f32cdde 2020-07-28 18:16 +0000)
```

```
$ which firefox 
/usr/bin/firefox
```

```
$ firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 68.10.0esr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox Browser* session with ***Firefox 48+*** versions, you have to use [Marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530302/how-can-geckodriver-firefox-work-without-marionette-running-python-selenium-3/44537094#44537094) mandatorily.

---

### Solution

The solution would be either to work with default setting of [marionette](/questions/tagged/marionette) or turn **`marionette`** to **True** as follows:

```
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = True
```

Comment: I tried to set marionette mode True, but got the error : "Unable to find a matching set of capabilities"

Comment: @t2solve I'm fine with that error and that can be solved as well. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement please. Stackoverflow contributors will be  happy to help you out.

Comment: I do understand, but actually it's not solving my problem, because at the time my code is not executable, it seems not be "the solution"  but I do see the focus is changing somehow

Comment: @t2solve To address `Unable to find a matching set of capabilities` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601126/unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-with-selenium-3-4-3-firefox-54-0/44601664#44601664), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002958/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a/52006033#52006033) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953524/selenium-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-despite-driver-being-in/53953692#53953692) discussion.

Answer (score 0):

you added the parentheses for DesiredCapabilities

```
cap = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
cap['marionette'] = False
```

or you can use webdriver_manager library which will help to get rid of a lot of headaches

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

and use it like this

```
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.log.level = "trace"
options.headless = True

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
capabilities["marionette"] = False

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

this setup helps you have the latest browser version for selenium, your error could be caused by the unmatching versions

Comment: I change my code and tried without parentheses, but still its the same effect

Comment: thanks again,  this seems to be a really hand way of getting the driver dependency, but it didn't solved the issue, I also found after 30 seconds a new error message, please see the updatet question

Comment: the error is clear, you r pointing the path to firefox instead of gecko driver, also it looks like u r trying to use a profile there, you should update the code question also

Comment: check my question, i updated it, with pointing towards the profile problem